# Gekko ARX models where data needs cutting

Tags: gekko, autoregressive-models

I am used to using commercial packages for linear model identification. In these packages, a section of the step test data can be marked as bad (e.g. when the unit tripped or was operating abnormally). I have been using the Gekko ARX routine to give training in MPC methods, and now would like to use it to develop models for a project.  What should I do to cut the data I do not want the identifier to use?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest jupyter notebook or jupyter lab when working with data. These options may help:

1- Using pandas DataFrame:

[image: Sample Data]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('signal_df.csv')
df
```

[image: DataFrame]

```
df[['y1', 'y2']].plot()
```

[image: sample plot]

```
df[['y1', 'y2']].drop(df.index[290:521]).dropna().plot()
```

[image: mod data]

2- Using SysID App (Based on Gekko):

```
pip install seeq-sysid
```

Download the `sysid_notebook.ipynb` notebook from:

https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/Seeq/tree/main/SysID%20Addon

Run the notebook using Jupyter notebook (AppMode), Jupyter Lab or VSCode.

[User Guide](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imanbabaei/appb/master/Sysid%20Ex.mp4)

Now you can import the results as a gekko model:

[image: import to gekko]

Read more:

https://byu-prism.github.io/Seeq/

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built into the seeq-sysid application. See the notebook -sysid_notebook.ipynb on the github page: [Jupyternotebook_example](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/Seeq/blob/main/SysID%20Addon/sysid_notebook.ipynb).
The app can also be used even if you don't have seeq.
Just set the dataframe properties of the app before running, i.e app.capsule_df, signal_df and tags_df. Then refresh the data_editor by running:

```
app.load_data_editor_action()
app.done_data_editor_action()
```

In the top left corner of the app you can do some basic data editing.
Select "Data Editor" and then you can cut the dataset before fitting the model.

[image: Seeq_dataeditor]

Below is an example

[image]